# Check if an implicit exists in a match case

Tags: scala, playframework

The Play Framework provides a method of converting objects to JSON via an implicit `Writes`.

```
def toJson[T](o: T)(implicit tjs: Writes[T]): JsValue
```

I have a partial function that is processing messages, some of which may be serializable to JSON if a Writes exists. How can I write a case that matches objects for which an implicit Writes exists?

```
override def receive = {
  case obj:/*(T where there exists an implicit Writes[T])*/ =>
    return Json.toJson(obj)
  case other =>
    return Json.obj("unknown" -> other.toString)
}
```

Essentially what I want is a shorter version of

```
case obj:ClassA =>
  return Json.toJson(obj)
case obj:ClassB =>
  return Json.toJson(obj)
case obj:ClassC =>
  return Json.toJson(obj)
// ... repeat 20 times for all the classes where I know I have a Writes
```

I tried making like an `unapply` that accepts an implicit but I can't get case to accept that without a syntax error.

Comment: Implicits are a compile time feature, there is little sense in matching them on objects for runtime behavior. All you need to do is require the method takes an implicit evidence for `T`. If it doesn't find one, that compiler will tell you at compile time.

Comment: The problem is that the object I'm matching is Any and I have 20+ implicit Writes. I want to write one case for "an object that is one of the classes for which an implicit Writes exists". That should be possible at compile time, right? It's just a shorter version of enumerating 20+ types myself

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test if implicit conversion is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717868/test-if-implicit-conversion-is-available)

Comment: I tried expanding the question a little. I don't see how the linked question answers mine... Apologies if I'm being dense. I'm still learning Scala.

Comment: I found another question which mine does actually duplicate but the answer is not what I was hoping for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015658/play-2-2-match-if-there-exists-an-implicit-json-converter

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

## 1. Require all `Writes[ClassA]`, `Writes[ClassB]`, etc in your function

You might have to define another partial function and have `receive` call that since you don't have the signature

## 2. Use the `Writes` instance directly to convert to Json

```
// companion object of ClassA
object ClassA {
  val jsonWrites: Writes[ClassA]
}
```

And since inside the case matching scope you know it's a ClassA, you can use the Writes[ClassA] instance directly and everything will typecheck.

```
case obj: ClassA =>
  return ClassA.jsonWrites.writes(obj)
```

EDIT:
A third option that is both less error prone and flexible is to define a list of functions that 1. check whether an `obj: Any` is an instance of `T` and if so converts it to Json.

Here's a minimal snippet I have working using Scala worksheet. See `checkIsInstanceAndConvertToJson`:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

case class Json(str: String)

trait Writes[A] {
  def writes(obj: A): Json
}

// Generate a function that
// 1. Checks whether an object (Any) is an instance of `T`
// 2. Convert it to Json if it is
// The implementation of checking function. All unsafety is encapsulated
def checkIsInstanceAndConvertToJson[T: Writes](implicit t: ClassTag[T]): Any => Option[Json] = (obj: Any) => {
  if (t.runtimeClass.isInstance(obj)) {
    Some(implicitly[Writes[T]].writes(obj.asInstanceOf[T]))
  }
  else None
}

// ==========
// USAGE
// ==========

object Foo {
  implicit val jsonWrites = new Writes[Foo] {
    override def writes(obj: Foo) = Json("Foo")
  }
}

class Foo

object Bar {
  implicit val jsonWrites: Writes[Bar] = new Writes[Bar] {
    override def writes(obj: Bar) = Json("Bar")
  }
}

class Bar


// Defining a list of functions that checks whether
// an object is of an instance, and if so, converts it to Json
val checkFuncs = Vector[Any => Option[Json]](
  checkIsInstanceAndConvertToJson[Bar],
  checkIsInstanceAndConvertToJson[Foo]
)

val t: Any = new Bar

val iter = checkFuncs.iterator

var json: Option[Json] = None
while (json.isEmpty && iter.hasNext) {
  val func = iter.next()
  json = func(t)
}

println(json)
```

The above snippets prints `Some(Json(Bar))`